# CakePHP cacheHelper - appController not found error

Tags: php, cakephp, caching

I added CacheHelper to my app.
In my APP/Config/core.php I have

```
Configure::write('Cache.check', true);
```

In APP/Config/bootstrap.php I have

```
Configure::write('Dispatcher.filters', array(
  'AssetDispatcher',
  'CacheDispatcher'
));
```

In my controller I have:

```
public $helpers = array('Text', 'Cache');
public $cacheAction = "1 hour";
```

I don't have any callbacks directly in this controller nor in the AppController.
The problem is that each page loads only one time (for example – after cache is cleared). On second request I'm getting back

```
Fatal Error

Error: Class 'AppController' not found
```

If cache is turned off everything works well.

CakePHP version is 2.2.3

**Debug Log:**

```
 2012-12-24 12:21:00 Error: Fatal Error (1): Class 'AppController' not found in    [/Volumes/../app/Controller/NewsController.php, line 2]
 2012-12-24 12:21:00 Error: [FatalErrorException] Class 'AppController' not found
 #0 /Volumes/../lib/Cake/Error/ErrorHandler.php(161): ErrorHandler::handleFatalError(1,     'Class 'AppContr...', '/Volumes/Data/D...', 2)
 #1 [internal function]: ErrorHandler::handleError(1, 'Class 'AppContr...', '/Volumes/../D...', 2, Array)
 #2 /Volumes/../lib/Cake/Core/App.php(926): call_user_func('ErrorHandler::h...', 1, 'Class 'AppContr...', '/Volumes/../D...', 2, Array)
 #3 /Volumes/../lib/Cake/Core/App.php(899): App::_checkFatalError()
 #4 [internal function]: App::shutdown()
 #5 {main}
```

**NewsController:**

```
<?php
class NewsController extends AppController {
public $components = array('Security', 'ImageTool', 'Uploader');
public $paginate = array(
        'fields' => array('News.id', 'News.created'),
        'limit' => 5,
        'contain' => array(),
        'order' => array('News.id' => 'DESC'));

public $helpers = array('Text', 'Cache');
public $cacheAction = "1 hour";
```

Comment: Does your Error/Debug log add any other information? Or is this all the error feedback you are having?

Comment: Was googling for it with `https://www.google.nl/search?q=cakephp+cache+appcontroller+not+found` when I noticed the first result. It seems like SO is crawled very, very quickly :)

Comment: I think I can guess what happens on `line 2 of the NewsController`, but can you add this line of code (+ and - a few lines?) to your question as well? Maybe something is wrong here. I have no idea, but let's check :)

Comment: Once again – question updated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The only "warning" I am seeing in the docs notes: `If you have view variables that contain un-serializable content such as SimpleXML objects, resource handles, or closures you might not be able to use view caching.` but I do not think this is causing the bug. Or does it?

Comment: And could you try it with another controller? What if you make new controller named `MyTestController` which contains nothing but the Caching? Just a simple cached `index.ctp` which says "hello world" is enough. What happens then? If that works, you will at least know where to look :)

Comment: No, unfortunately result is the same - Error: Class 'AppController' not found

Comment: Then I have really no idea. Try [updating](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/zipball/2.2.4) Maybe that will solve it magically?

Comment: I'll take a break for day because now I need to quickly finish another task. Once again – thank you for trying to help me, I will try updating tomorrow.

Comment: Your welcome. As long as you post the answer if you found it I'll be happy :) Maybe I will run into the same problem and I would like to know how to solve it by then :)

Comment: Ok I just downloaded fresh and shiny 2.2.4, unpacked it, added controller for testing purposes, and all cache related stuff to core and bootstrap. And wuala –  Class 'AppController' not found. So it looks like I make configuration error and I can't catch it :(. I will be glad if you can by yourself download cake, and make some testing controller and view  with working CacheHelper functionality. And after it upload app to dropbox or something. Thanks in advance. P.S. I can upload my test app if you need it.

Comment: Weird, I followed [this](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/cache.html) part of the books but it doesn't seem to do anything at all. I set the $cacheAction to '1 hour', but I have also tried 36000 as an integer. Even with debug set to 0 my `/tmp/cache/views` folder stays empty. At least I think I should be able to find the cached views there? But no errors, that's for sure.

Comment: In my app `/tmp/cache/views` populates with cached files but I got errors. May be you can take a look on my test app, I wonder that you may notice differences between your test app and my. Here is the link https://www.dropbox.com/s/nxptwzbar5ckm73/cakephp.zip Test controller is named "News" so ../news should show you page at first load and error on the second one. ../news/clear to clear cache.

Comment: I probably found the answer (thanks to euromark).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

And the winner is...
App::uses('AppController', 'Controller'); at the top of controller code.

```
App::uses('AppController', 'Controller');

class NewsController extends AppController {
public $helpers = array('Cache');
public $cacheAction = array(
    'index'  => 48000
);

public function index() {

}
public function clear() {
    clearCache();
}
}
```

I don't know why this is not yet included in the Cookbook.

Comment: Haha seriously? It is kinda important to "use" the AppController. It is in the PagesController for example ;)

Comment: Yep. But I didn't find information about it in the Cookbook. I always thought that App::uses('AppController', 'Controller'); in the AppController.php is enough.

Comment: This is odd that it is not in the cookbook and without debug on, cake crashes. Thanks a lot for this!

Comment: I don't understand the reason behind this error .can anyone explain please why this happen when we use cache helper?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
namespace App\Controller;
use App\Controller\AppController;
class StudentsController extends AppController{}
```

this Worked for me.